# How to make JTextPane(or JEditorPane) change line automatically after the text line reaches the Pane's size?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am new to *Java GUI programming* and I am currently making a simple text editor.

**Question:**

Currently when the text line's length crosses the TextPane's width the horizontal scrollbar sets on and the typing continues, what I want is that as soon as the line becomes TextPane's width long automatically the typing continues from the next line.

For e.g. Like in MS-Word or this very editor box in which I am typing this question.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping of text is the default processing for a JTextPane. That is try the code from the following `SSCCE` and you will see that it works:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add( new JScrollPane( new JTextPane() ) );
                frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
                frame.setSize(100, 200);
                frame.setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, if your code doesn't work you are doing something strange.

Check out [No Wrap Text Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/) for a couple of way to disable wrapping and make sure your code is NOT doing this.

If you still can't solve your problem then post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: My code is exactly the same and while I even tried the above code, same thing happened. I now think I have been less explanatory in my question. Sir, what I want is something like this comment box itself! Whenever I reach the end of the line while typing the cursor automatically moves to the next line. i.e. no horizontal scroll bar shows up and you can continue typing from the next line.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution to my problem! Thank you so much for answering. I just used textarea and did textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);. but this is not working with JTextPane? Please explain this to me.

Comment: `I even tried the above code` - then if it doesn't work, it is a version or platform issue. Line wrapping occurs automatically for me using JDK7 on Windows 7.